# python3 - after successfully reading CSV file into 2D Arrary - how to print a single cell by index?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, multidimensional-array, cell-array

I want to read a CSV File (filled in by temperature sensors) by python3.

Reading CSV File into array works fine. Printing a single cell by index fails. Please help for the right line of code.

This is the code.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import array as ar

#Reading the CSV File

#  date;seconds;Time;Aussen-Temp;Ruecklauf;Kessel;Vorlauf;Diff
#  20211019;0;20211019;12,9;24;22,1;24,8;0,800000000000001
#  ...
#  ... (2800 rows in total)

np = pd.read_csv('/var/log/LM92Temperature_U-20211019.csv',
            header=0,
            sep=";",
            usecols=['date','seconds','Time','Aussen-      Temp','Ruecklauf','Kessel','Vorlauf','Diff'])

br = np # works fine
print (br) # works fine - prints whole CSV Table :-) !
#-----------------------------------------------------------
# Now I want to print the element [2] [3]  of the two dimensional "CSV" array ... How to manage that ?

print (br [2] [3]) # ... ends up with an error ...

# what is the correct coding needed now, please?
```

Thanks in advance & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Give the name of the column, not the index:

```
print(br['Time'][3])
```

As an aside, you can read your data with only the following, and you may want `decimal=','` as well:

```py
import pandas as pd
br = pd.read_csv('/var/log/LM92Temperature_U-20211019.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')
print(br)
```

Comment: Thanks very much - you made my day ... I never would have come to this solution - my respect.

Comment: Please, allow me an additional question: Supposed the header line was missing in the .csv file - what would be the CSV read parameters and how could I then address/print the cell [2] [3], please?

Comment: @Karl Use `header=None` and `index_col=False`.  Read with `br[2][3]`.  The columns will be numbered in that case.  Read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and experiment.  That's all I did 

Comment: Hi Mark, many thanks - great support. I am a Python newbie (experienced in C/C++) ... ! Never thought, that the different imported classes are so specific that fundamentals in coding "language/notation" can change (e.g. array processing)! This also has sensitized me for future Root Cause Analysis in general. Thanks